# Sorting in C for under Directory

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have a directory, named Directory, and this Directory contains a directory named one. 
So Directory, Directory/one.
If I give in arguments Directory Directory,
I will have the following : Directory, Directory, Directory/one Directory/one, because I sort by ascii.
I'd like to sort it to have the following : Directory, Directory/one, Directory, Directory/one, but have no idea how to do this.

Could you please help ?

ps : All directories are stored in a linked list.

Thank you,

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the result for each argument and then add them together (without re-sorting).

pseudo-code:

```
for each argument
  get dirlist for argument
  sort dirlist
  add dirlist to output
next argument
```